# Prolog Clear List of negative elements without using cuts

Tags: prolog

How do I write a procedure in Prolog that clears a list of integers of its negative elements and returns the result in a new list? Without using cuts but can use negation.

For example:

```
?- filter([1,0,-6,7,-1],L).
L = [1,0,7];
no
```

Comment: filter([],[]).
filter([H|T],S) :- H<0, filter(T,S).
filter([H|T],S) :- H>=0, filter(T,[H|S]).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have it almost right.
Your solution was:

```
filter([],[]).
filter([H|T],S) :-
  H<0,
  filter(T,S).
filter([H|T],S) :-
  H>=0,
  filter(T,[H|S]).
```

The base case and the case where the item is negative are right.
The problem is with the last case. Once you checked that the item is nonnegative you know that the item will be on the resulting list. Therefore you should do the recursion and return a list that contains the element you have checked (H) and the list returned by recursion. Thus, the last clause should be

```
filter([H|T],[H|S]) :-
  H>=0,
  filter(T,S).
```

Comment: I get error when trying execute your code, please, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34401942/visual-prolog-maximum-number-of-anyflow

Comment: @Src. Do not be mistaken about the actual code to take home from this answer!

Comment: @Src. gusbro does **not** endorse the above definition of `filter/2` (comprising 3 clauses)... In fact, he suggests *replacing* the last clause with `filter([H|T],[H|S]) :- H>=0, filter(T,S).`

Comment: @repeat have you seen my question?

Comment: @Src. Yes. It contains `findNegative([H1|T1], S) :- findNegative(T1, [H1|S]).` which is nonsense.

Comment: @repeat Ok, so maybe it is my fault. I will explain what i want to achieve: i just want to append HEAD element of FIRST list, to the HEAD of SECOND. So i decided that it is a right way of doing that. Any suggestions how to make it non nonsense?

Answer (score 1):

In SWI-Prolog you can use `exclude/3`

```
?- exclude(negative, [-1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1], L).
L = [0, 0.5, 1].
```

provided that you have a definition for `negative/1`:

```
negative(Number) :-
    Number < 0.
```

Answer (score 0):

Using recursion for the last case,

I'd write :

```
filter([],[]).

filter([H|T],S) :-
  H<0,
  filter(T,S).

filter([H|T], L) :- 
 H>=0, 
 filter(T, S),
 append([H],S,L).
```