# How to find the positive numbers in a list in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I want to write a code in prolog that gets a list and find its positive numbers and adds them into a new list as below :

```
?- findPositives([-1,2,3,-5,-7,9],Result)
Result : [2,3,9]
```

How can I write this code?

Comment: Have you made any attempts at a solution that you can show?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prolog Clear List of negative elements without using cuts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6670603/prolog-clear-list-of-negative-elements-without-using-cuts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`tfilter/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30211229/4609915):

```
positive_truth(N, true) :-
   N >= 0.
positive_truth(N, false) :-
   N < 0.

?- tfilter(positive_truth, [-1,2,3,-5,-7,9],Result).
   Result = [2,3,9].
```

Alternatively, using `library(clpfd)`:

```
pos_truth(Expr, Truth) :-
   Expr #>= 0 #<==> Bool,
   bool01_truth(Bool, Truth).

bool01_truth(0,false).
bool01_truth(1,true).

?- tfilter(pos_truth, [-1,2,3,-5,-7,9],Result).
   Result = [2,3,9].
?- tfilter(pos_truth, [X,Y],Result).
   Result = [],     X in inf.. -1, Y in inf.. -1
;  Result = [Y],    X in inf.. -1, Y in 0..sup
;  Result = [X],    X in 0..sup,   Y in inf.. -1
;  Result = [X, Y], X in 0..sup,   Y in 0..sup.
```

Comment: Thanks but I meant without using tfilter/3

Comment: @AmirJalilifard: Without `tfilter/3` it would be most probably incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

this would be the simple way:

```
find_positives( Ns , Ps ) :- findall( X , ( member(X,Ns) , X > 0 ) , Ps ) .
```

But I suspect that your instructor would like you to figure out a recursive solution on your own. Ergo...

```
find_positives( []     , []     ) .
find_positives( [N|Ns] , [P|Ps] ) :- N >  0 , find_positives(Ns,Ps) .
find_positives( [N|Ns] ,    Ps  ) :- N =< 0 , find_positives(Ns,Ps) .
```

Note that you could save a comparison by introducing a deterministic cut, thus:

```
find_positives( []     , []     ) .
find_positives( [N|Ns] , [P|Ps] ) :- N > 0 , ! , find_positives(Ns,Ps) .
find_positives( [_|Ns] ,    Ps  ) :- find_positives(Ns,Ps) .
```

And make it a little more succinct by collapsing the 2nd and 3rd clauses by a 'soft cut'/conjunction (`->/2`):

```
find_positives( []     , [] ) .
find_positives( [N|Ns] , R  ) :-
  ( N > 0 -> R = [P|Ps]; R = Ps ) ,
  find_positives(Ns,Ps) .
```

Whether that improves comprehension or not is left up to you.

Comment: Your first and 2nd answer lacks a `N = P`. Your 2nd succeeds for `find_positives([1],[])` but should rather fail.