# Visual Prolog: Maximum number of anyflow

Tags: list, prolog, visual-prolog

I get an error message `Maximum number of anyflow variants (1000) exceeded` when trying to execute this code:

```
findNegative([], []).
findNegative([Q|V], Y) :-
   Q > 0,
   !,
   findNegative(V, Y).
findNegative([H1|T1], S) :-
   findNegative(T1, [H1|S]).
```

Same when trying to execute code from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6671142/4829408

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following code:

```
find_negatives([],        [] ).
find_negatives([E|Es],    Xs ) :- E >= 0, find_negatives(Es, Xs).
find_negatives([E|Es], [E|Xs]) :- E <  0, find_negatives(Es, Xs).
```

Sample query:

```
?- find_negatives([1,2,3,-1,-2,-3,0,1,2,0,-1], Xs).
   Xs = [-1,-2,-3,-1]
;  false.
```

Comment: Thank you! And why don't you use CUT(!)?